# How to run saved script in Sql Server Data Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I am just learning SSDT.

I connect to a database, write some SQL, and then save it to a file as part of the project.  All that works fine.

But now I want to open and run the script.

When I open the script, the toolbar at the top is missing which I normally use to run the script.

I don't understand how to get this toolbar back except by selecting "New Query" which opens up the SQL window with the toolbar, and then copy and pasting the SQL into the new window.

It seems like the Editor would automatically bring up the toolbar.

I am using VS15 with the latest SSDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite by accident, I found the answer to this question:

To make the toolbar appear, set the build action to "None".  Then it will open the Editor with the toolbar.

In other words, the right way to add a script that you want to run at design time is to select "Add -> Script ->" then select "Script (Not in build)".

Then it will open with the expected toolbar.

If it is included in the build, the toolbar will not show.  I am guessing that this is by design as a non-build script would normally be run at design time.

Comment: Yes it is by design. Ed already explained the difference between connected and disconnected development approach.

Answer (score 5):

The main thing to understand is that the idea of ssdt is that you declare how you want the database to be (including setting up data in pre/post deploy scripts) and then make a database the same as your project by doing a publish.

A publish is:

- Build the project which generates a dacpac
- Use sqlpackage.exe (or the api) to compare the dacpac to a database and generate a script for you to run (ssms, sqlcmd, etc) or update the database for you.

This is all called disconnected development, what you are talking about is connected development and you can do it by specifically opening a query window and running queries but anything you do there is effectively outside of ssdt - you may as well be running them from within ssms.

For more about connected development see:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/connected-development-with-sql-server-data-tools/

(by me!)

ed

Comment: Good point about the difference between connected and disconnected development.  Interesting that you just wrote this article. Good Read!

Answer (score 0):

You must understand how SSDT works. Here you work with the model and the model is not related to the database.

Now according to your question. I might be wrong but as far as I understand that you would like to run some queries in your SSDT project scripts. You can do following things:

1. Go to project properties;
2. Go to debug
3. Set your connection to database in "Target Connection String"

Now in all your files (except table scripts) you can execute SQL scripts by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+E.

Test workflow that I sometimes do:

1. open stored procedure file in project
2. change CREATE to ALTER
3. Now it highlights that you have error in the file and the build fails but you can continue working and executing it straight to the DB
4. As soon as you finish change back from ALTER to CREATE and save the file

Comment: That is a good tip on setting the Target Connection String in the Debug Properties.  I didn't realize that was there.